# List of contacts swing

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I need to implement ui for list of contacts like in skype. An contact represented by custom class(JContact) which derived from JPanel. I tried to use different layouts but not received expected result. Main frame has next structure.

JFrame -> JPanel(contactsPanel)-> JScrollPane(scrollContacts)->JPanel(contactPanel)

scrollContacts.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
scrollContacts.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

If use FlowLayout for contactPanel (see FlowLayout in  image)

Strange behavior i think, because expected what each contacts will one under one because indicate HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER for scrollContacts.

If use Grid or Box layout. Layout automatically re-size my panels, it's look very ugly. see Grid&Box layouts image.

Expected result see "expected" image

[----SEE IMAGE----](http://www.shareimage.org/images/4c9djnszxt9col91f2i.png)

I'm not native speaker, so please sorry for my bad English.Thank you for attention!

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the [Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html):

> The FlowLayout class puts components in a row, sized at their preferred size. If the horizontal space in the container is too small to put all the components in one row, the FlowLayout class uses multiple rows

So the result you get is expected.

> A GridLayout object places components in a grid of cells. Each component takes all the available space within its cell, and each cell is exactly the same size. If the GridLayoutDemo window is resized, the GridLayout object changes the cell size so that the cells are as large as possible, given the space available to the container.

So the result you get is also expected.

> When a BoxLayout lays out components from top to bottom, it tries to size each component at the component's preferred height. If the vertical space of the layout does not match the sum of the preferred heights, then BoxLayout tries to resize the components to fill the space.

So the result you get is also expected.

But, a box layout can contain glue components to avoid that.

I would thus use a vertical box layout, and add a vertical glue as the last component. Read [the tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html).

Comment: Ok. THanx. I did this:

`public void refreshContactsList(Set<IContact> contacts) {
                contactPanel.removeAll();
                Box contactsBox = Box.createVerticalBox();
                for (IContact contact : contacts) {
                    JContact jContact = new JContact(mediator, contact);
                 contactsBox.add(jContact);
                 contactsBox.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());}
                contactPanel.add(contactsBox);
                contactPanel.revalidate();
                contactPanel.repaint();}`

But got the same result as in case with grid layout.

Comment: You're adding a glue after each contact. You should add a glue only after the last one.

Comment: The other problem is that you probably didn't define the maximum height of your JContact component. Here's a working example: https://gist.github.com/4240355

Comment: Ok, i know about this, but can't because haven't enough rates for voting.